# The tracking Id should only be of the format UA-NNNNNN-N

Tags: google-analytics

The google analytics dashboard show my Tracking Code in `G-XXXXXXXXXX` format and the `react-GA` need it to be in `UA-NNNNNN-N`

How can I get it in `UA-NNNNNN-N` format, in my google console I searched `tracking info` but no page exists and it just show me

> In web-only properties, this is referred to as Tracking ID in format UA-XXXXXXXX-

Everything is works for me, google analytics can collect data now, my problem is events, when I send the following event nothing happens in dashboard

```
ReactGA.event({
  category: 'User',
  action: 'Created an Account'
});
```

Also in dashboard, when I want to `Add event` there is no `category` and `action` just `event name`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have to create a Universal Analytics Property (as shown in following image) and use the relative identifier UA-XXXXXXX-X:

[image]

Comment: I cannot find that option

Comment: Where is admin tab? I have no property setup option

Comment: You can see it when you create a new property

Comment: This will be discount it after July 2023

Answer (score 1):

> Universal Analytics properties will stop collecting data starting 1 July 2023. It’s recommended that you create a Google Analytics 4 property instead.

[image]

So you can use this [node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4) with GA_MEASUREMENT_ID