# Get events from react-ga

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I'm trying to implement Google Analytics in a SPA React-app to record events.

I have created a data stream in Google Analytics and got a measurement ID. Then I made a custom hook:

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga'

type GoogleAnalyticsReturn = {
    regEventGA: (
        category: string,
        action: string,
        value?: number,
        label?: string,
    ) => void
    initializeGa: (pageUrl: string) => void
}

const ga_measurement_id = 'INSERT CODE HERE'
const ga_debug = true

export const useGoogleAnalytics = (): GoogleAnalyticsReturn => {
    const initializeGa = (pageUrl: string) => {
        if (ga_measurement_id) {
            ReactGA.initialize(ga_measurement_id, {
                debug: ga_debug,
            })
            ReactGA.set({ anonymizeIp: true })
            ReactGA.pageview(pageUrl)
        }
    }

    const regEventGA = (
        category: string,
        action: string,
        value?: number,
        label?: string,
    ) => {
        ReactGA.event({
            category: category,
            action: action,
            value: value,
            label: label,
        })
    }

    return { regEventGA, initializeGa }
}
```

I then use the hook to initialize GA in App.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useGoogleAnalytics } from './utils/useGoogleAnalytics/useGoogleAnalytics'

function App(): JSX.Element {
    const { initializeGa } = useGoogleAnalytics()
    initializeGa(window.location.pathname)

    return (
        <MyComponent />
    )
}

export default App
```

In MyComponent, an event is sent:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useGoogleAnalytics } from './utils/useGoogleAnalytics/useGoogleAnalytics'

export const MyComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
    const { regEventGA } = useGoogleAnalytics()

    const handleClick = () => {
        regEventGA('My Component', 'Button click')
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>
            Click me!
        </button>
    )
}
```

When I'm clicking the button, console is printing:

```
[react-ga] called ga('send', fieldObject)

[react-ga] with fieldObject {"hitType":"event","eventCategory":"My Component","eventAction":"Button click"}

[react-ga] with trackers: undefined
```

But nothing is appearing on Google Analytics.

Comment: Fixed it by creating a Universal Analytics Property: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380395/12999775